# pusher android onEvent not being called

Tags: android, pusher

I'm using pusher-java-client 1.0.2 (tried the same with 1.0.0).
The android client subscribes to a channel, but events are not fired(onEvent not called).
While in my js client events do fire up for the same events.

```
    // Create a new Pusher instance
    mPusher = new Pusher(Defines.PUSHER_APP_KEY);

    mPusher.connect(new ConnectionEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(ConnectionStateChange change) {
            Logger.i("pusher: State changed to " + change.getCurrentState() +
                    " from " + change.getPreviousState());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String message, String code, Exception e) {
            Logger.e("pusher: There was a problem connecting! msg:" + message);
        }
    }, ConnectionState.ALL);

    Channel channel = mPusher.subscribe("test_chan", new ChannelEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscriptionSucceeded(String channel) {
            Logger.i("pusher: subscribed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(String channel, String event, String data) {
            Logger.i("pusher: channel=" + channel + " event=" + " data=" + data);
        }
    }, "test_event");
```

output log after sending some events:

01-03 15:47:02.884 pusher: State changed to CONNECTING from DISCONNECTED

01-03 15:47:04.403 pusher: State changed to CONNECTED from CONNECTING

01-03 15:47:04.709 pusher: subscribed

What could be the reason my onEvent callback is not fired when publishing a "test_event" in "test_chan"?

Answer (score 0):

**You must have to add 'client' before your eventName and use** '`-`'

```
Channel channel = mPusher.subscribe("test-chan",this, "client-test-event");
```

**Use ChannelEventListener with your Activity**

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ChannelEventListener{

...

@Override
            public void onSubscriptionSucceeded(String channel) {
                Logger.i("pusher: subscribed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onEvent(String channel, String event, String data) {
                Logger.i("pusher: channel=" + channel + " event=" + " data=" + data);
            }

}
```

Try to implement like this it will work; and let me know if it will help you or not :)

Comment: thanks but nope, doesn't work. I've contacted pubnub and talked with one of their engineers, unfortunately, the problem is not solved yet. might be in a later version. anyway, I stopped trying pubnub for now.

Comment: actually now i am working on chat app, and I have implemented pusher ; and it's working for me, can you send me code then I can give exact solution;

Comment: have u used trigger; eg: PusherConfig.channel.trigger("test_event", jsonMessage);

Comment: hey I found your problem; i have updated the above code; actually u must have to use 'client' key in event like: client-test-event

Comment: now it will work ; please let me know the current status; :)

Comment: Not worked for me,please post the changes if it working in your end

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Create a new Pusher instance

    HttpAuthorizer authorizer = new HttpAuthorizer("https://example.com");

    PusherOptions options = new PusherOptions().setCluster("mt1")
            .setEncrypted(true)
            .setWsPort(6001)
            .setWssPort(6001)
            .setAuthorizer(authorizer)
            .setHost("example.com");
    pusher = new Pusher("your-key", options);

    //connect
    pusher.connect(new ConnectionEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(ConnectionStateChange change) {
            Log.i(TAG, "State changed from " + change.getPreviousState() +
                    " to " + change.getCurrentState());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String message, String code, Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "There was a problem connecting! " +
                    "\ncode: " + code +
                    "\nmessage: " + message +
                    "\nException: " + e
            );
        }
    }, ConnectionState.ALL);

    // Subscribe to a channel
    // Bind to listen for events
    pusher.subscribe("channel-name").bind("event-name", new ChannelEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscriptionSucceeded(String channelName) {

            Log.d(TAG, "onSubscriptionSucceeded: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(PusherEvent event) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onEvent: data " + event.getData() + " user id " + event.getUserId());


        }
    });

    // Reconnect, with all channel subscriptions and event bindings automatically recreated
    pusher.connect();
```